# Adding multiple records in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I'm a newbie stumbling my way through creating my first rails application. I'm trying to add multiple records to a table from a nested form, and at the moment, only the last record is being added.

I'm working on a form that will allow a user to associate a mathematics equation with how it should be read under a given reading rule. In an abstract view, two simple records would be:

```
equation: "x-3", readingRule:"Simple", transcription"x take away three" 
equation: "x-3", readingRule:"Standard", transcription"x minus three"
```

I have four tables: 'equations', 'transcriptions', 'readingRuleSets', and 'tests'. A single test consists of the ids of an equation, a transcription, and a readingRuleSet.

I have a form, which has a text field for the user to select the id of the equation, and four text fields (associated with my four reading rule sets) for them to select the id of the transcriptions. When I hit submit, I want four new 'tests' added, one for each of the transcriptions. At the moment, Rails is adding only the last one.

I thought it was because the id's of the text fields are the same in the html source. I tried concatenating the field name with the index from each_with_index, but that left me with one record being added to 'test', and the reading_rule_set_id was null because I'd amended the name of the column with the index. So I've taken that out, read a lot more, watched railscasts 196, and I'm still stuck.

Relevant bits of code:

\app\models\test.rb

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :equations
  has_many :reading_rule_sets
  has_many :transcriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :equations :transcriptions :reading_rule_sets
end
```

The other three tables have their respective 'belongs_to's.

\app\views\tests:

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Reading Rules and Transcriptions </legend>
            <% ReadingRuleSet.all.each_with_index do |rrs, index| %>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label><%= rrs.name %></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <%= f.text_field :transcription_id %>
                        <%= f.hidden_field :reading_rule_set_id, :value =>rrs.id %>
                        <!--# .to_s + index.to_s-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

app\controllers\tests_controller.rb

```
# POST /tests
# POST /tests.json
def create
@test = Test.new(test_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @test.save
    format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @test }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /tests/1
# PATCH/PUT /tests/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @test.update(test_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @test }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_test
      @test = Test.find(params[:id])
    end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def test_params
  params.require(:test).permit(:equation_id, :reading_rule_set_id, :transcription_id, :transcription_transcription)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your test_params.

See Rails guide [nested-form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)

For my information, it is possible for the nested of nested and nested polymorphic model.

```
#example
def class_info_params
  params.require(:class_info).permit(.....
    classes_attributes : [:id, :_destroy, , class_times_attributes:[:id, :day, :start_time, :_destroy]],
    my_subcategories_attributes: [:id,:_destroy, :subcategoriable_id, :subcategoriable_type, :subcategory_id])
end
```

But I think it is better to pass json data (made by js JSON.stringify) because of complexity(?), intuition(?) and above all, front-end framework (e.g. angularjs (ng-model))

p.s. (?) means it could be only for me.